# Python: importar el valor de una variable en una función, desde otro script

Tags: python, funciones, variables, python-import, telegram

Agradecería su ayuda para resolver lo siguiente (de seguro es algo sencillo pero soy nuevo en esto).

Estoy haciendo un bot en Telegram con Python y tengo 2 scripts.

La idea es que al sript principal llegue un nombre como mensaje enviado por el usuario, le mande ese nombre a una función de otro srcipt, ésta lo valide, y le devuelva al script principal si el usuario existe o no.

En el programa **mainbot_agenda.py** tengo la función `validuser()` que, al recibir el mensaje del usuario, lo guarda en la variable `username`. Luego llama a otra función en otro programa **gsheets_helper** que se llama `valid_user()`:

```
from gsheets_helper import gsheet_functions
gs = gsheet_functions()

def validuser (update,context):
    username = update.message.text # Aquí 
    update.message.reply_text(gs.valid_user())
```

Aquí les muestro el programa **gsheets_helper.py** y la función en cuestión:

```
def __init__(self):
        # esto es info que se necesita para conectarse con GSheets
        scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        CREDS_JASON,
        scope
        )
        # Autorizar a Google Sheets (gsepread) a que use las credenciales (creds) que tienen la clave del archivo json
        self.client = gspread.authorize(creds)
        self.gsheet = self.client.open_by_key(USER_PASS_SHEET_KEY)


def valid_user (self):
        from mainbot_agenda import username
        sheet = self.gsheet.worksheet(USER_PASS_SHEET) #<--------- se conecta con tabla en Google Sheets
        findcell = sheet.find(username)                #<--------- busca el valor de username en la tabla de Google Sheets
        if findcell == None :
            answ = 'Usuario inexistente'
        else :
            answ = 'Usuario existente'
        return answ
```

El problema es que al momento de ejecutar la función `validuser()` que llama a la función `valid_user()`sale el siguiente error:

*cannot import name 'username' from 'mainbot_agenda'*

Qué es lo que puede estar fallando?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Cual sería el problema? El unico problema que veo es que escribiste la palabra return toda en mayusculas (cuando debería estar en minusculas). Quizá tu programa está dando un error relacionado a la API, pero desconozco de ese tema.

Comment: Gracias @DanteS. por tu comentario! Ahí modifiqué un poco la consulta para que sea claro el problema. Al momento de querer importar la variable `username` sale el error: _cannot import name 'username' from 'mainbot_agenda_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible importar una [variable local](https://www.codigopiton.com/variables-locales-y-globales-en-python/) (al menos no de forma convencional). Esto se debe a que ésta solo existe dentro de la función. Es decir, username existe dentro de la función validuser, pero no fuera de ésta.

En este caso, la mejor y más prolija solución es hacer que la función `valid_user` acepte un argumento el cual sea el nombre de usuario.

`valid_user` quedaría así:

```
def valid_user (self, username):
    sheet = self.gsheet.worksheet(USER_PASS_SHEET) #<--------- se conecta con tabla en Google Sheets
    findcell = sheet.find(username)                #<--------- busca el valor de username en la tabla de Google Sheets
    if findcell == None :
        answ = 'Usuario inexistente'
    else :
        answ = 'Usuario existente'
    return answ
```

Y `validuser` así:

```
def validuser (update,context):
    username = update.message.text # Aquí 
    update.message.reply_text(gs.valid_user(username))
```

Comment: Lo probé y funciona a la perfección! Millones de gracias! Leí decenas de consultas acá y no lo podría sacar! Viva la comunidad Stack Overflow! Leeré más sobre variables en Python. Gracias denuevo. Abrazo

Comment: De nada Santiago :D Por cierto, agradecería que aceptases la respuesta c: